# Why didn't BizTalk Scope Catch this MissingPropertyException

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2020

Very similar to this question: [Handling Exceptions in Biztalk which don't get caught by Scope shape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18338580/handling-exceptions-in-biztalk-which-dont-get-caught-by-scope-shape), but yet a totally different error.

I was creating a tutorial on how to catch errors in BizTalk, and low and behold, it didn't catch my error at all.  I had just shown how to use promoted fields, so I dropped a file that didn't have the element that was promoted.  If I put a divided by zero ( x = x / x where x =0) in the top of "Do XPaths" expression then it catches fine.

So I know the reason for the error, and how to fix it.  But I'm asking why the scope/catch didn't catch it.

Error:

```
Shape name: Do XPaths ShapeId: 3c3c7019-6322-4fe8-85eb-3292601c6039
Exception thrown from: segment 2, progress 2
Inner exception: There is no value associated with the property 'SchemaLesson.Airline' in the
message.
Exception type: MissingPropertyException
Source: Microsoft.XLANGs.BizTalk.Engine
```

Orch "Transaction Type" is "Long Running" and so is my Scope.  I also tried both with "Transaction Type" set to "None", and same result.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you are catching a `System.SystemException` rather than a `System.Exception`.  XLang exceptions are not a member of `System.SystemException` but are of `System.Exception`.  `System.Exception` will catch a lot more.

See also [System.Exception vs System.SystemException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189959/system-exception-vs-system-systemexception)

Comment: Thanks, Great catch; I thought I picked System.Exception; they look so similar; Have done this 100s of times, and it was driving me crazy.

Comment: @NealWalters Yes,I have made that mistake before, hence I knew it straight off as it is seared into my memory ;-)